# Javascript IE8 wrapper for existing onclick event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have to call another function before the original `onclick` event fires, I've tried a lot of different paths before I've come to following solution:

```
function bindEnableFieldToAllLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        var onclick = link.getAttribute('onclick');
        link.onclick = new Function("if(linkClickHandler()){"+onclick+"}");
        console.log(link.getAttribute('onclick'));
    }
}
```

This does the trick in Firefox and Chrome but IE8 is acting strange, it seems that the function that's in the `onclick` variable isn't executed.
I've already added `console.log` messages that get fired after the if statement is true and if I print out the `onclick` attribute I get following:

```
LOG: function anonymous() {
if(linkClickHandler()){function onclick()
{
if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('hoedanigheidForm'),      {'hoedanigheidForm:j_id_jsp_443872799_27':'hoedanigheidForm:j_id_jsp_443872799_27'},'');}return false
}}
}
```

So it seems that the function is on the `onclick` of the link and the old `onclick` function is on it as well.

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: Instead of using onclick and trying to bind 2 methods at the same event, you can use addEventListener and add as many event handlers as you want...

Comment: @Givi addEventListener is not supported in IE8

Comment: @RayNicholus Yes you're right if he want cross browser solution it's easy to write custom function with addEventListener and attachEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an *onclick* attribute on a *HTMLElement*..

```
<span id="foo" onclick="bar"></span>
```

Now,

```
var node = document.getElementById('foo');
node.getAttribute('onclick'); // String "bar"
node.onclick; // function onclick(event) {bar}
```

The latter looks more useful to what you're trying to achieve as using **it still has it's original scope** and you don't have to re-`eval`uate code with `Function`.

```
function bindEnableFieldToAllLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) function (link, click) { // scope these
        link.onclick = function () { // this function literal has access to
            if (linkClickHandler())  // variables in scope so you can re-
                return click.apply(this, arguments); // invoke in context
        };
    }(links[i], links[i].onclick); // pass link and function to scope
}
```

---

Further, setting a *named function* inside an *onclick* attribute (i.e. as a *String*) doesn't achieve anything; [the function doesn't invoke or even enter the global namespace](http://jsbin.com/ixapol/1/edit) because it gets wrapped.
Setting an anonymous one is worse and will throw a *SyntaxError* when *onclick* tries to execute.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want, executing what is inside `linkClickHandler` first, and then executing the `onclick` event.  I put in a basic cross browser event subscribing function for your reuse.

```
bindEnableFieldToAllLinks();    

function bindEnableFieldToAllLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        var onclick = link.getAttribute('onclick');
        onEvent(link, 'click', function() { 
            linkClickHandler(onclick);
        });
        link.onclick = undefined;
    }
}

function onEvent(obj, name, func) {
    if (obj.attachEvent) obj.attachEvent('on' + name, func);
    else if (obj.addEventListener) obj.addEventListener(name, func);    
}
function linkClickHandler(funcText) {
    alert('before');
    var f = Function(funcText);

    f();
    return true;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFzGn/)